# Python re I want to split at all punctuation except for the - symbol

Tags: python, string, split, python-re, except

```
re.split("\\W+", words)
```

I have the code above which splits the string at all punctuation but how do I split it at all punctuation except for the '-' symbol?

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.split(r'[^-\w]+', words)`

Where `^` inside the character group indicates not to split on (`-` or `any alphabet`) characters.

Comment: i forgot to mention the i wanted to keep the delimiters so i took your solution and added () like this re.split("([^-\w])",words) this seems to have worked for me. thank you